# Asp.Net MVC 3 Routing - Generating Outgoing URL using UrlHelper uses request RouteData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Asp.Net MVC 3, when creating outgoing link for example with UrlHelper will use RouteData from current request. I dont really understand why.

Here is my routing

```
routes.MapRoute("car-location", "{car}/{location}/search", 
                new {
                    controller = MVC.Home.Name,
                    action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Search
                },
                new {
                    car = "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+",
                    location = "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
                });

routes.MapRoute("car-only", "{car}/search-car",
                new
                {
                    controller = MVC.Home.Name,
                    action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Search
                },
                new
                {
                    car = "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
                });
```

Ok, now I try to generate links:

```
@Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = MVC.Home.Name, action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Search, car = "SUV" })
@Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = MVC.Home.Name, action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Search, location = "NY", car = "SUV" })
```

The result is correct when current URL is /SUV/search-car

- /SUV/search-car
- /SUV/NY/search

and when current url is /SUV/NY/search they both turn into

- /SUV/NY/search
- /SUV/NY/search

So into the first link {location} is transfered from current request. I dont want my links to be changing :)

I tried putting empty location

```
$@Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = MVC.Home.Name, action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Search, car = "SUV", location = "" })
```

so it generates this (uses correct route but adds this as parameter)

/SUV/search-car?location=NY

Howto generate links that point to the same action and have different set of routing data and be independent of current request url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the Route name, car-location, or car-only as the first argument of the RouteUrl method like so

```
@Url.RouteUrl("car-only", new { controller = MVC.Home.Name, action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Search, car = "SUV", location = "" })
```